# How does Qt::DirectConnection act when used in multi-threaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qt-connection

Though `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::AutoConnection` (in certain cases) are preferred in a multithreaded environment, I am asking this question for my understanding purpose.

1. If signal `MySignal()` is emitted in thread A & slot `MySlot()` belongs to object of thread B. Both are connected via `Qt::DirectConnection`, how does the execution happen? i.e. If thread A sends a signal to thread B, while thread B is executing in middle of some function `foo()`. Will the slot `MySlot()` be called just after the `foo()` finishes or will it be called in parallel to `foo()`?
2. Are there any scenario when `Qt::DirectConnection` is desirable over others in a multithreaded app?

Comment: A signal emitted and connected to a slot with `Qt::DirectConnection` is nothing but a plain function call.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any scenario when `DirectConnection` is desirable over others in a multithreaded app?

Yes, if your thread `B` is *only* executing in a single function and has no event loop, then `DirectConnection` is the *only* choice you have. Using `AutoConnection` or `QueuedConnection` will not work because the corresponding slot call event will not be processed in `B` or anywhere else.

Another reason for `DirectConnection` might be if your parameters are not serializable/deserializable [using the Qt meta object system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1). If the conditions for `Qt::DirectConnection` are satisfied (the slot is thread-safe), you can use it instead (be wary about consequences - see following text).

Another thing you have to take into account is signal distribution across multiple slots. If you use `DirectConnection` and the slot needs to wait on a mutex, other slots that were connected after that said slot will not be activated until the slot has returned. Using `QueuedConnection` in this case will provide for a non-blocking signal distribution. Then, the thread B will block (in its qt-internal event handler for the slot-call event), instead of thread A in its "emit" statement.

Another thing you have to take into account is slot invocation order. If you issue multiple `emit` statements one after another, and slots of the same object are called using `QueuedConnection`, they are called in this order, because what's behind it are ordinary slot-call events. If some of these slots are `DirectConnection`, then they are called synchronously in the emitting thread, with no order guarantee relative to the other queued slot invocations!

*Edit*: I think there's also an interesting case with [QObject::deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater). I recommend connecting to it using `Qt::DirectConnection`. This function is thread-safe and will send a delete-later event to the object's target thread. What's more, the function also handles the case where the object's thread has no running event loop (in which case the object is deleted when its thread exits). If you were to use `Qt::QueuedConnection` and there's no event loop in the target thread, you would have created a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

> If thread A sends a signal to thread B, while thread B is executing in
>   middle of some function foo(). Will the slot MySlot() be called just
>   after the foo() finishes or will it be called in parallel to foo()?

Unfortunately (and as you suspect) `Qt::DirectConnection` is precisely that and `B::MySlot()` will be invoked on thread A concurrently with whatever is already happening on thread B -- `foo()` in this case.  So, without any other form of synchronization the use of `Qt::DirectConnection` is generally a bad idea when the sender and receiver may be on different threads.

If you really *do* require the concept of a synchronous cross-thread signal/slot call then you might want to look at [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)